# Ruby unexpected |, expecting =

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a do block with index. But I keep getting: syntax error, unexpected '|'

This is my code:

```
def same_char_collapse(str)
  chars = str.split("")

  while chars.each.with_index do | letter, i |
    if letter[i] == letter[i + 1]
      letter[i] = ""
      letter[i +1] = ""
    end
    break
  end
end
```

The error I am getting:

```
/tmp/file.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected '|'
...hile chars.each.with_index do | letter, i |
...                              ^
/tmp/file.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting '='
...ach.with_index do | letter, i |
...                              ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code you posted is formatted so poorly that I cannot under stand it. Can you please fix the formatting and indentation?

Answer (score 2):

This line doesn't make sense:

```
while chars.each.with_index do |letter, i|
```

I think you just meant to use:

```
chars.each.with_index do |letter, i|
```

A while loop, in any language, takes the form: `while(conditional) ....`. You don't have a conditional here, so it's not a valid use case for `while`.

On the other hand, [methods such as `each` will](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-each):

> Call the given block once for each element in `self`, passing that element as a parameter.

Note: You also could have used [`chars.each_with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) instead of `.each.with_index`.